# GROUP BY Converted AS/400 date format into SQL date

Tags: sql, date, db2-400

**Ultimately I want to take some data and group it by month in SQL in the AS/400 (Green Screen).**

Here is the initial SQL query and its corresponding result:

```
SELECT ITNBRV, /* Item */
       ODDTRV, OQTYRV /* Order due due, Order quantity */
  FROM ORDREVLA /* MRP Recommendations */
 WHERE ITNBRV = '17000' OR ITNBRV = '19000' /* Returns only items 17000, 19000 */
```

[image: Query Result Screen Shot]

**I would like to take that data and summarize it like this:**

```
Item number Order Due Date  Order Quantity
   17000         11/17           1296
   17000         12/17           1296
   17000         01/18           3564
   17000         02/18           3888
   19000         11/17          68100
   19000         12/17           1800
   19000         01/18          23220
```

This is what I've used to convert the date format:

```
  SELECT ITNBRV,
         month(
         substr(ODDTRV,4,2) ||'/'||
         substr(ODDTRV,6,2) ||'/'||
         substr(ODDTRV,2,2)) ||'/'||
         year(
         substr(ODDTRV,4,2) ||'/'||
         substr(ODDTRV,6,2) ||'/'||
         substr(ODDTRV,2,2)) AS Month_Year,
         OQTYRV
    FROM ORDREVLA
   WHERE ITNBRV = '17000' OR ITNBRV = '19000'
```

With the following result:

[image: Converted Dates]

I tried to use GROUP BY with the same conversion numbers:

```
  SELECT ITNBRV,
         month(
         substr(ODDTRV,4,2) ||'/'||
         substr(ODDTRV,6,2) ||'/'||
         substr(ODDTRV,2,2)) ||'/'||
         year(
         substr(ODDTRV,4,2) ||'/'||
         substr(ODDTRV,6,2) ||'/'||
         substr(ODDTRV,2,2)) AS Month_Year,
         OQTYRV
    FROM ORDREVLA
   WHERE ITNBRV = '17000' OR ITNBRV = '19000'
GROUP BY (month(
         substr(ODDTRV,4,2) ||'/'||
         substr(ODDTRV,6,2) ||'/'||
         substr(ODDTRV,2,2)))
```

But got this error message:

```
Column ITNBRV or expression in SELECT list not valid.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not familiar with AS/400 SQL, but it looks like you need to group by INTBRV and add an aggregation to ORDREVLA.

```
SELECT 
         ITNBRV,
         month(
         substr(ODDTRV,4,2) ||'/'||
         substr(ODDTRV,6,2) ||'/'||
         substr(ODDTRV,2,2)) ||'/'||
         year(
         substr(ODDTRV,4,2) ||'/'||
         substr(ODDTRV,6,2) ||'/'||
         substr(ODDTRV,2,2)) AS Month_Year,
         SUM(OQTYRV) as OQTYRV_Total
FROM 
         ORDREVLA
WHERE 
         ITNBRV = '17000' OR ITNBRV = '19000'
GROUP BY (month(
             substr(ODDTRV,4,2) ||'/'||
             substr(ODDTRV,6,2) ||'/'||
             substr(ODDTRV,2,2))),
             ITNBRV
```

Comment: DB2 for i (AS/400 SQL) follows the SQL standard so you have it correct here. That would be the ISO/IEC 9075 standards, parts 1-4, 10, 11, and 14. v7.2 and v7.3 support 2016 standards, v7.1 supports the previous standards.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy: Something is still off, now I get the error message "Column ODDTRV or expression in SELECT list not valid."

Comment: @Charles Thanks, I literally just added that as an edit before you commented, so hopefully it is peer reviewed and added.

Answer (score 0):

personally, I prefer to handle this with a common table expression (CTE)..

```
with mmyy as (
SELECT 
         ITNBRV,
         month(
         substr(ODDTRV,4,2) ||'/'||
         substr(ODDTRV,6,2) ||'/'||
         substr(ODDTRV,2,2)) ||'/'||
         year(
         substr(ODDTRV,4,2) ||'/'||
         substr(ODDTRV,6,2) ||'/'||
         substr(ODDTRV,2,2)) AS Month_Year,
         OQTYRV
FROM 
         ORDREVLA
WHERE 
         ITNBRV = '17000' OR ITNBRV = '19000'
)
select 
   itnbrv, month_year, sum(oqtyrv) as OQTYRV_Total
from
   mmyy
group by
   itnbrv, month_year
```